# Current Month Facebook Friends Birthdays in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-android-sdk

I am writing an app in which i am fetching list of **Facebook Friends** using *Hackbook Sample Code* but now i want to fetch list of **Facebook Friends those birthdays in Current Month**, to get list of all Friends i am using this code:

```
 public static void requestFriends(FacebookRequest facebookRequest) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "requestFriends(" + ")");
    String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by birthday_date";
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "fql.query");
    params.putString("query", query);
    FacebookUtility.asyncRunner.request(null, params, new FacebookRequestListener(FacebookRequestListener.FRIENDS, facebookRequest));
}
```

Still i am using below code to get List of *Friends those Birthdays in Current Month*:

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+ 1;

    String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in " +
    "(select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())AND birthday_date >= '" + month + "/01' AND birthday_date <= '" + month + "/31' ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
```

but i am not getting any record, where i am missing ?

Comment: You want upcoming birthdays only till month end or all birthdays in current month?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Thanks for reply, i need to show all birthdays those are coming in current month(query will show automatically for all next month coming birthdays as well and so on...)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is calculate the following values using language you are using and use them in your FQL:

```
1st's day of the current month (17),
Today's month of the year (01)
End date day of the current month (31)
```

Make sure days and months are formatted using dd and MM respectively (padded with zero in case of single digits). Then your FQL would look like this:

```
SELECT name, birthday_date
  FROM user 
  WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
  AND strlen(birthday_date) != 0
  AND (
       substr(birthday_date, 0, 2) = '01'
       AND substr(birthday_date, 3, 5) >= '01'
       AND substr(birthday_date, 3, 5) < '31'
  ) 
  ORDER BY birthday_date
```

This will then return the friends who's birthday falls between 01 Jan and 31 Jan.

**Update:**
Calculate current month and last date of current month:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
int currentmonth=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1

public static Date getLastDateOfMonth(int year, int month) {
   Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
   return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: yes i agree with you to get birthdays only for January Month, i can use this query String revisedQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND birthday_date >= '01/01' AND birthday_date <= '01/31' ORDER BY birthday_date ASC"  but i want to make it more dynamic...

Comment: @Liza: What do you mean by more dynamic? I am not saying to put '01' and '31' static values. Calculate start and end date, month by programming language( android ) and put those variables there. What else?

Comment: what you have written i knew that already, and you are talking about Android language please show me that code by writing in any language you use, then i will use that in my Android Program...

Comment: @Liza: Means you want to know current month and last date of month by programming language( dynamically )?

Comment: You asked me in a comment on another question to have a look at this question, but I don't think I can add much to Somnath Muluk's answer and comments. Just use his query example and build the query String dynamically with the time input as variables. If you are unsure about how to build Strings in Java dynamically you'll need to read up on it first. Lots of web tuts available.

Comment: @GunnarKarlsson same for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to get the current months facebook friend in ascending order..

**`SELECT name, birthday, uid, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT  uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())AND birthday_date >= '01/01/2013' AND birthday_date <= '31/01/2013' ORDER BY birthday_date`**