# Sort Facebook Friends Birthdays List Month Wise in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-android-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hackbook sample code to Fetch List of Current Month Facebook Friends Birthdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373862/hackbook-sample-code-to-fetch-list-of-current-month-facebook-friends-birthdays)

I have made a program in which i am *Fetching* list of my all *Facebook Friends*..

Now i want to make my module more *custom for users* and want to allow user to see their Friends List Month Wise

**Question:**

```
How to sort Facebook Friends List those birthdays in Current Month or Week only...
```

Code to Fetch List of all Friends:

```
 public static void requestFriends(FacebookRequest facebookRequest) {
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "requestFriends(" + ")");
String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by birthday_date";
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "fql.query");
params.putString("query", query);
FacebookUtility.asyncRunner.request(null, params, 
new   FacebookRequestListener(FacebookRequestListener.FRIENDS, facebookRequest));
}
```

Code to Fetch List of Friends those birthdays in January Month:

```
String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())AND birthday_date >= '01/01' AND birthday_date <= '01/31' ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you already know how to get friends from a specific month. 
While I don't know android I believe you just need to get the current month and insert it in the fql.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())AND birthday_date >= '" + month+ "/01' AND birthday_date <= '" + month+ "/31' ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
```

Or something similar.