# How to Show ListView Items in Tabs

Tags: android, facebook, android-listview, android-facebook

In **Contacts Tab**, trying to fetch list of all Facebook Friends

In **Month Tab**, trying to fetch list of Facebook Friends those Birthdays in Current Month

In **Week Tab**, trying to fetch list of Facebook Friends those Birthdays in Current Week

I have written code for all and i am *not getting any error while build and run my program*, but i am not getting list of friends in any of the Tab.

Please let me know, where i am doing silly mistake...where i am missing..

*TabSample.Java :-*

```
public class TabSample extends TabActivity {

String response;

private static JSONArray jsonArray;
public static TabHost mTabHost;
private MyFacebook fb = MyFacebook.getInstance();
public static MyLocalDB db = null;
private BcReceiver bcr = null;
private BcReceiverAlarm bcra = null;
private PendingIntent mAlarmSender;
private boolean isAlarmSet;
private ProgressDialog busyDialog;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(TabSample.this, 0, new Intent(
            TabSample.this, BdRemService.class), 0);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    if (db == null) {
        db = new MyLocalDB(this);
        db.open();
    }
    if (!fb.isReady()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "TabSample- initiating facebook");
        fb.init(this);// after finishing, this will call loadContents itself
    } else {
        loadContents();
    }
    busyDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    busyDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    busyDialog.setMessage("Refreshing");
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }
    response = getIntent().getStringExtra("FRIENDS");
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        FacebookUtility.displayMessageBox(this,
        this.getString(R.string.json_failed));
    }
    setTabs();

}
private void setTabs() {

    addTab("Contacts", com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.ContactTab.class);
    addTab("Month", com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.MonthTab.class);
    addTab("Week", com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.WeekTab.class);

}
private void setupTabHost() {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

}
private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, Intent intent,
        int id) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag, id);
    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview)
    .setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}
private void addTab(String labelId, Class<?> c) {
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    intent.putExtra("FRIENDS", response);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);
    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
    R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text,
final int id) 
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
    R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
    return view;
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
if (bcr == null) {
    bcr = new BcReceiver();
    registerReceiver(bcr, new IntentFilter(MyUtils.BIRTHDAY_ALERT));
}
if (bcra == null) {
    bcra = new BcReceiverAlarm();
    registerReceiver(bcra, new IntentFilter(MyUtils.ALARM_RESET));
}
super.onResume();
}
public void loadContents() {
if (fb.getFriendsCount() > 0) {
    return;
}
fb.setMyFriends(db.getAllFriends());
if (fb.getFriendsCount() > 0) {
    notifyTabSample(Note.FRIENDLIST_CHANGED);
} else {
    fb.reLoadAllFriends();
}
// 4. initiate alarm
if (!isAlarmSet) {
    setAlarm(true);
}
}
private void setAlarm(boolean isON) {
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
if (isON) {
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, MyUtils
            .getAlarmStartTimeAsLong(MyUtils.getAlarmHour(), MyUtils
                    .getAlarmMinute()), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            mAlarmSender);
    isAlarmSet = true;
    Log.v(TAG, "TabSample- alarm set");
} else {
    am.cancel(mAlarmSender);
    isAlarmSet = true;
    Log.v(TAG, "TabSample- alarm cancelled");
}
}
public void notifyTabSample(Note what) {
switch (what) {
case FRIENDLIST_RELOADED:
    db.syncFriends(fb.getMyFriends());
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(MyUtils.FRIENDLIST_CHANGED));
    break;
case FRIENDLIST_CHANGED:
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(MyUtils.FRIENDLIST_CHANGED));
    // setup timer
    break;
default:
    break;
}
}
```

*ContactTab.Java :-*

```
public class ContactTab extends ListActivity {
private MyFacebook fb = MyFacebook.getInstance();
private BcReceiver bcr = null;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private List<MyFriend> list;
private ProgressDialog busyDialog;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    busyDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    busyDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    busyDialog.setMessage("Refreshing");
}

private void refreshList() {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            list = fb.getAllFriends();
            Log.v(TAG, "contactstab- refresh called. " + list.size());
            adapter = new MyAdapter(ContactTab.this, list);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (bcr == null) {
        bcr = new BcReceiver();
        registerReceiver(bcr, new IntentFilter(MyUtils.FRIENDLIST_CHANGED));
    }
    refreshList();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    MyFriend friend = (MyFriend) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(ContactTab.this, PersonalGreeting.class);
    intent.putExtra("fbID", friend.getFbID());
    intent.putExtra("name", friend.getName());
    intent.putExtra("pic", friend.getPic());
    startActivity(intent);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return (super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu));
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.globalGreeting:
        intent = new Intent(ContactTab.this, com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.GlobalGreeting.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.Settings:
        intent = new Intent(ContactTab.this, com.chr.tatu.sample.friendslist.Settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

public class BcReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                refreshList();
            }
        });
    }
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        //busyDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
   }
```

*MonthTab.Java :-*

```
public class MonthTab extends ListActivity {
private MyFacebook fb = MyFacebook.getInstance();
private BcReceiver bcr = null;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private List<MyFriend> list;
private ProgressDialog busyDialog;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    busyDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    busyDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    busyDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
    busyDialog.show();
    refreshList();
}

private void refreshList() {
    // list = fb.getFilteredFriends(Filter.MONTH);
    list = fb.getFilteredFriends(Filter.MONTH);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(MonthTab.this, list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    busyDialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (bcr == null) {
        bcr = new BcReceiver();
        registerReceiver(bcr, new IntentFilter(MyUtils.FRIENDLIST_CHANGED));
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    MyFriend friend = (MyFriend) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MonthTab.this, PersonalGreeting.class);
    intent.putExtra("fbID", friend.getFbID());
    intent.putExtra("name", friend.getName());
    startActivity(intent);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return (super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu));
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.globalGreeting:
        intent = new Intent(MonthTab.this, GlobalGreeting.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.Settings:
        intent = new Intent(MonthTab.this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

public class BcReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                refreshList();
            }
        });
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: have you got any exception or error in your logcat?if any,please post it for a better view of your question.

Comment: @AndroidLearner no i did not get any error, it is the main reason i am not able to understand the problem....

Comment: Have you set INTERNET Permissions in your manifest file?

Comment: @AndroidLearner friend i have made 4 tabs, in 3 out of 4 i am not getting ListView in Tabs, but in 1st tab i am getting data, but these three tabs belongs to another sample which i have included in my existing project, if i will run same sample code which i have downloaded then i am getting data in that also but like i said i am using two different programs in one therefore only i am getting some minor problem but don't know what???

Comment: @AndroidLearner see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373862/current-month-facebook-friends-birthdays-in-android   i did not get any solution to get Current Month Facebook Friends Birthdays that's why only i have inserted another sample code in my existing one..

Comment: That means are you adding `FRIENDS` tab dynamically in your layout?

Comment: try without adding `FRIENDS` tab and see what happens :)

Comment: @Liza deleted your yahoo mail id...???